# Transferring email to API

Tags: javascript, api, controller

I'm trying to transfer an email to the controller and for some reason it doesn't work, I receive 404 error.

When I change the email variable to a string without '.' it works.

That's how it looks in the client side -

```
    function postTeacherSuccess(newpass) {
        let passWord = newpass;
        let email = $("#uEmail").val();
        api = "../api/Teachers/" + passWord + "/" + email;
        ajaxCall("PUT",api, "", putPassSuccess, putPassError);
    }
```

That's in the controller -

```
    [HttpPut]
    [Route("api/Teachers/{passWord}/{email}")]
    public void ChangePass(string passWord, string email)
    {
        Teachers t = new Teachers();
        t.setTpass(passWord, email);
    }
```

Any help is appreciated!! Thanks

Comment: Since it is a PUT request why do you need password and email in the url and not just send them in the request body?

Comment: I need to update the DB with the new password that was sent to reset the pass.

Comment: Fine but that doesn't mean it needs to be in the url for a PUT request. A password in a url is a very insecure idea also

Comment: True, but the URL is not visible anywhere
Why not if in the DB I use a UPDATE method in SQL?

Comment: A normal PUT request sends data in the request body. Would mean you would pass that data into `ajaxCall()` as another parameter and add it to body of whatever ajax method you are using

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it using

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
```

in the Web.confing under

`<system.webServer`>